# Umbraco property editor not working

Tags: javascript, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm running Umbraco version 7.9.2 and following [this tutorial](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Tutorials/Creating-a-Property-Editor/) to learn how to create custom property editors.

My first step was to create a folder called MarkDownEditor

[image: MarkDownEditor]

My second step was to create a file named package.manifest.json

```
{
  //you can define multiple editors
  "propertyEditors": [
    {
      /*this must be a unique alias*/
      "alias": "My.MarkdownEditor",
      /*the name*/
      "name": "My markdown editor",
      /*the icon*/
      "icon": "icon-code",
      /*grouping for "Select editor" dialog*/
      "group": "Rich Content",
      /*the HTML file we will load for the editor*/
      "editor": {
        "view": "~/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/markdowneditor.html"
      }
    }
  ],
  //array of files we want to inject into the application on app_start
  "javascript": [
    "~/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/markdowneditor.controller.js"
  ]
}
```

I then created two files: markdowneditor.controller.js and markdowneditor.html in the MarkDownEditor directory

markdowneditor.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="My.MarkdownEditorController">
        <textarea ng-model="model.value"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

markdowneditor.controller.js

```
angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("My.MarkdownEditorController",
    //inject umbracos assetsService
    function ($scope, assetsService) {

        //tell the assetsService to load the markdown.editor libs from the markdown editors
        //plugin folder
        assetsService
            .load([
                "~/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/lib/Markdown.Converter.js",
                "~/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/lib/Markdown.Sanitizer.js",
                "~/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/lib/Markdown.Editor.js"
            ])
            .then(function () {
                //this function will execute when all dependencies have loaded
                alert("editor dependencies loaded");
                console.log('stuff has loaded!');
            });

        //load the separate css for the editor to avoid it blocking our js loading
        assetsService.loadCss("~/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/lib/Markdown.Editor.css");
    });
```

Finally, I registered the editor in the Umbraco CMS, put it in a simple document type and finally visited the page in multiple browsers.

[image: Dashboard]
[image: viewing]

And... I see nothing. It seems like the editor is working (I think) but I don't get why I'm not seeing my alert or console.log that's contained in the controller. What did I do wrong? I've tried multiple browsers so I know it's not a caching issue and I've made sure to rebuild the project in visual studio.

Edit 1 :

Per suggestions, I've tried modifying the assetService file paths since ~ seems to be a C# thing and my controller is a javascript file. It now looks like this

```
    .load([
        "/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/lib/Markdown.Converter.js",
        "/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/lib/Markdown.Sanitizer.js",
        "/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/lib/Markdown.Editor.js"
    ])
```

However, I'm still not seeing an alert or a console log.

One thing I did realize I was doing wrong was not including my markdown value in the markdown template. I've done that and now see the content that I put in the editor when creating a new markdown page.

[image: Template]

[image: TemplateView]

Comment: The `~/` notation you use for loading the files probably wont work, since its a C# thing. So the files don't get loaded and the promise is never fullfilled, so no alert. Replace `~/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor` by `./` and I think you'll see an alert

Comment: I did what you suggested. Nothing. I noticed I'm not seeing my content on the page. So I made sure to add My.MarkdownEditorController to the makrdownTester template. I now see my content but I still don't see my console.log or alert.

Comment: What if you replace only the `~`, so change `~/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/lib/Markdown.Converter.js` to `/App_Plugins/MarkDownEditor/lib/Markdown.Converter.js`. Could you show the updated code?

Comment: post has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution. My package.manifest file had a .json extension. When that was removed, everything worked perfectly. For anyone coming across this, the ~ works perfectly fine in the javascript file.